# Cuando no entendemos la respuesta que nos dan a nuestra pregunta, ¿Sería correcto formular otra pregunta a cerca del entendimiento de esta?

Tags: discusión

Me ha ocurrido ya en un par de ocasiones que formulo una pregunta y la respuesta es válida, ya que copio la respuesta y modifico aquello que veo necesario para que mi código funcione.

Sin embargo, debido a que mis conocimientos en programación no son muy amplios, **no logro entender del todo la respuesta que me han dado**, pese a que sí me haya servido para mi proyecto. En estos casos considero que en un comentario no sería capaz de desarrollar perfectamente mi duda pero sí en otra pregunta que podría enlazar con la pregunta original. **¿Sería correcto hacer esto o es mejor intentar formular mi duda en un comentario?** También considero que responder a esto en otro comentario sería más costoso para el que formuló la respuesta.

Comment: Depende un poco de la importancia de la duda. Yo personalmente te recomendaría lo primero pedir la explicación de lo que no entiendas al autor de la respuesta. Este de esa manera puede, bien en un comentario, bien ampliando su respuesta, tratar de resolver tu duda. Si así no consigues una respuesta satisfactoria, si puedes realizar una nueva pregunta, siempre cumpliendo con las normas y requisitos del sitio.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

La **zona de comentarios** esta destinada a:

- Pedir aclaraciones a quien pregunta o responde si su publicación no es clara o le hacen falta detalles
- Preguntarle si posibles errores o *typos* son al momento de copiar su código o así lo tenía
- Indicarle que la pregunta o  respuesta incumple con alguna de las reglas

Dado lo anterior considero que:

Si quien te responde aporta un contenido que ayuda a solucionar el problema pero este mismo no termina de quedar claro entonces deberías:

Solicitarle resuelva tus dudas respecto a:

- Terminología desconocida
- Fragmentos de código que no son claros tales como:

  - clases
  - traits
  - instancias
  - etc.
- Implementación de la solución

Considerando que la posible solución no solo debe ser clara a quien la aporta sino además al OP y sobre todo a la comunidad que en un futuro la llegué a consultar entonces si es un paso no solo útil sino además necesario el solicitar aclaraciones